# How do I set the amount of text to be displayed in IJulia

Tags: julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

In IJulia I have a large array/table to display:
But it keeps getting cut off:

```
In [1]:

rand('a':'z', 100,100)

Out[1]:

100x100 Array{Char,2}:
 'g'  'n'  's'  'v'  'i'  'b'  'v'  'f'  …  'v'  'y'  'p'  'o'  'b'  't'  'x'
 'w'  'c'  'y'  'c'  'z'  'g'  'v'  'x'     'w'  'q'  'm'  's'  'v'  'd'  'v'
 'g'  'o'  'm'  'e'  'x'  'x'  'o'  'z'     'q'  'y'  'o'  't'  'x'  'r'  'p'
 'i'  'b'  'w'  'u'  'f'  'g'  'l'  'k'     'c'  'a'  'q'  'q'  'o'  'b'  'p'
 'r'  'y'  'r'  'f'  'h'  'z'  'm'  'w'     'l'  'i'  'a'  'd'  'm'  'r'  'c'
 'u'  'k'  'q'  'b'  'a'  'm'  'q'  's'  …  's'  'f'  'o'  'c'  'r'  'i'  'm'
 'a'  'q'  'q'  'p'  'k'  's'  'd'  'j'     'l'  'p'  'j'  'o'  's'  'b'  'o'
 'e'  'k'  'p'  'k'  'x'  't'  'u'  'u'     'z'  'y'  't'  'c'  'm'  'k'  'x'
 'n'  'n'  'e'  'w'  'm'  'c'  'g'  'd'     'n'  'b'  's'  'x'  'k'  'd'  'c'
 'e'  'c'  's'  'i'  'k'  'y'  'v'  'p'     'w'  'g'  'e'  'm'  'k'  'j'  'z'
 't'  'h'  'v'  'w'  'l'  'c'  'i'  'e'  …  'r'  'i'  'u'  'w'  'j'  'q'  'a'
 'y'  'r'  'c'  'q'  't'  'y'  'd'  'n'     'e'  'd'  'f'  'x'  'd'  'l'  'b'
 's'  'd'  'r'  'y'  'x'  'u'  'c'  't'     'r'  'j'  'p'  'k'  'e'  'c'  'k'
   ⋮                        ⋮            ⋱              ⋮                    
 'j'  'p'  'h'  'h'  'e'  'g'  'q'  'p'     'a'  'w'  'o'  'o'  'x'  'k'  'n'
 'z'  'f'  'n'  'm'  'f'  'q'  'b'  'l'     'w'  'o'  'i'  'e'  'n'  't'  'h'
 'h'  'i'  'r'  'h'  'g'  'e'  't'  'o'  …  'v'  'l'  'y'  'r'  'q'  'h'  'u'
 'y'  'm'  'c'  'd'  'w'  'b'  'z'  'g'     'm'  'y'  'g'  'h'  'y'  'w'  'n'
 'q'  't'  'h'  'a'  'y'  'w'  's'  'o'     'd'  'z'  'j'  'o'  's'  'n'  'm'
 'i'  'c'  't'  'u'  'j'  'r'  'n'  'd'     'y'  'g'  'm'  'r'  'x'  'i'  'z'
 't'  'q'  'm'  'h'  'j'  'x'  't'  'n'     'n'  'k'  'z'  'c'  'f'  'z'  'e'
 'w'  'j'  'i'  'y'  'c'  'z'  's'  'k'  …  'k'  'r'  'c'  'y'  'p'  'o'  'h'
 'o'  'k'  'x'  'e'  'w'  'y'  'k'  'o'     'u'  'h'  'b'  'z'  'o'  'e'  'h'
 'e'  'l'  'd'  'w'  'k'  'c'  'h'  'x'     's'  'x'  'i'  'c'  'j'  'k'  'o'
 'y'  'e'  'q'  'c'  'k'  'f'  'x'  'w'     'z'  'y'  'v'  'p'  'b'  'e'  'n'
 'j'  'n'  'w'  'i'  'u'  'u'  'w'  'l'     'd'  's'  'v'  'b'  's'  'q'  'h'
```

This is normally handy, but right now I don't want it.
How do I disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the amount of characters to display before truncation by setting the global env options as shown below:

```
ENV["LINES"] = 150
ENV["COLUMNS"] = 300
```

You may still have issues with its wrapping though.

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to display all of it, you can call `print` on it:

```
print(rand('a':'z', 100,100))
```